# Xpage edit/read mode error: The form does not contain an input: $$viewid

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

need some help about my xpage application not getting into read/edit mode. Here is the scenario. I created a view that contains a couple of entries in my landing page, the user clicks the link on the view and go to another page to open the document. In that page I've got set to edit, set to read mode buttons, just like the tutorial on the bootstrap4xpage. And here is where the error occur, I click the "set to edit" or "set to read" button and a pop up shows saying : " Problem submitting the page. The form does not contain an input:$$viewid" I'm new to both notes and xpage so I don't have the skills yet to identify this kind of error. Thank you in advance.

By the way I use bootstrap4xpage template.

Comment: Check the name of your partial refresh control

Comment: Did you mean the partial refresh in the view? Its default value is empty.

Comment: I mean behind the buttons. Try changing all places to full fresh, and if that work continue from that.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I don't know if this matters but the forms are in a tab.

Comment: Could you add the Code to the post?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late post. I found that using the <form> tag of bootstrap instead of <div> tag produces that error.I think there is some issue about using that tag in xpage. Thanks for the help I will tag this now as answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the `<form>` tag of bootstrap instead of `<div>` tag produces this kind of error.I think there is some issue about using that tag in xpage. What it is, well, that's something I don't know. But anyhow changing my `<form>` tags into `divs` did solved the error.

Comment: Yup, the issue you described in your answer above is correct. Could you update this answer please as it is not quite correct was it :-). Thanks!