# Domino xAgent gives 500 Command not handled exception - $$viewid ID not present

Tags: xpages

Dear domino cognoscenti,

I've just written a simple xAgent using an xpage which works for GET requests but when I submit a POST request I get an `Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception` with the following detail `CLFAD0384E: Page instance not found. The $$viewid ID was not present in a POST request` (thanks Per for the hint).

Here's the code. What am I doing wrong? Do xpages not handle POST requests by default? Do I have to enable this or something?

Thanks very much for your time!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">
    <xp:this.resources>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:      
            var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
            var requestMethod = exCon.getRequest().getMethod();
            var response = exCon.getResponse();
            var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();

            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            
            writer.write(requestMethod);
            writer.endDocument();
        }]]>
    </xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
</xp:view>
```

**Edited 16 October 2022**
I've tried the following:

- Added `viewState="nostate"` to `xp:view`. (thanks Mark for that)
- Had no code in the `afterRenderResponse` other than logging - still
  get the same problem.
- Used code in the `beforeRenderResponse` - same problem.
- Tried the `restService` - same.

The only thing that appears to fix it is:

- Introduce a field called `$$viewid` and set this to the value '!!' or '!0!' or similar.
- Use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) Web API on the browser to build the request body.
- Send it as `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`.

Sending it as plain text, application/json etc doesn't work. For some reason the xpage won't accept other encoding types.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Check the stack trace in the XPages log file for details on the error

Comment: I get "CLFAD0384E: Page instance not found. The $$viewid ID was not present in a POST request". From here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380359/significance-of-hidden-fields-viewid-xspsubmitid-xspexecid-xspsubmitv it appears that this is associated with the backend controls (although there are none on my xpage). How do I get to know what value I need? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add, I've tried adding a field to the form performing the POST request with the name $$viewid and tried several values and I'm getting the error 'String Transform operation not supported'. If there's any walkthrough to handling POST request via xAgents you can point me to instead, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Just an update, I found something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396385/xpage-edit-read-mode-error-the-form-does-not-contain-an-input-viewid regarding the use of the <form> tag so I also did a POST request using the fetch API in the browser and I'm getting the same result 

Comment: Take a look at Jakarta EE for XPages for building a proper API: https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.xsp.jakartaee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) protection as detailed in [this](https://www.focul.net/excellent-support-from-hcl-including-xpages/) blog post. When creating an xpage, in `xsp.properties`, the setting `xsp.csrf.protection=true` needs to be set to `false` (annoyingly it's not part of the UI, you have to go to the source tab).

The explainer from the blog post is as follows.

> If you look in a new NSF the xsp.properties contains a setting
> xsp.csrf.protection=true .
>
> This enables a built-in framework for CSRF protection  and was very
> easily retrofitted to our existing NSFs.
>
> When this feature is enabled every XPage contains a token such as

```
<input type=”hidden” name=”$$viewid” id=”view:_id1__VUID” 
value=”!1to6ah3iyy1uc2gquai14d7ik!”>
```

> If the returned XPage does not
> have this same token then an error is generated. The error will be
> CLFAD0253E: Cannot find a page instance corresponding to the ID:
> $$viewid=!aaaaaaaaaa!. It may have expired. Try loading the web page

Setting this to false prevents this from occuring and the code works as expected (however see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74124107/12571484) for the `multipart/form-data`) Obviously there are risks so this isn't ideal but it's the cause of the problem seen. Setting this from true to false stops this from occurring.

Thanks to Sean Cull at Focul for pointing this out. If following this path, we'd have to code our own CSRF token handler.

Thanks to everyone else who contributed above. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but it might help to add viewState="nostate" to the xp:view. That's a good idea for XAgents anyway. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482575/xpages-falling-out-of-server-side-cache) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I do this a lot - though using Java beans. Let me show you:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false" viewState="nostate">
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:ServiceController.process()}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
</xp:view>
```

Not sure if this is an important difference but I use the "beforeRenderResponse" event...

In my Controller bean I have this public method:

```
public void process() {
    String method = null;
    try {
        setLanguage(null);
        method = Util.getHttpRequest().getMethod();
        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(method)) {
            processPostRequest();
        } else {
            processGetRequest();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Make sure any uncaught errors are logged and a proper response is returned
        sendResponse(new Error(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
    }
}
```

The "Util" class has these helpers:

```
public static ExternalContext getExternalContext() {
    return getFacesContext().getExternalContext();
}
public static XSPContext getXspContext() {
    return XSPContext.getXSPContext(getFacesContext());
}
public static HttpServletRequest getHttpRequest() {
    return (HttpServletRequest) getExternalContext().getRequest();
}
```

In the `processPostRequest()` method I get the data from the request through the request reader. In my sample I use Json to parse the contents to JSON like this:

```
List<PostObject> postList = new ArrayList<PostObject>();
JsonJavaFactory factory = JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx;
JsonJavaObject jsonObjs = (JsonJavaObject) JsonParser.fromJson(factory, Util.getHttpRequest().getReader());
```

As you send plain text you would just read the data from the reader.

HTH - happy coding ;-)

/John